# Disable specific day in Jquery date picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to disable all days with out Monday and Friday in Jquery date picker. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What threw you off might be the hidden `$.datepicker.noWeekends` method, which is really what you're after. So, what you really need to do is:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day == 1 || day == 5), ''];
    }
});
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/william/fsEpP/2/

Comment: This code can only disable weekends. But I want disable only monday and friday.

Comment: I thought you meant Monday through Friday. But, seriously, you could have worked out the answer quite easily by looking into the `$.datepicker.noWeekends` method... (see updated answer...)